# Give different color to each stack in stacked bar in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

As the question states, I want to give different color to each stack in the stacked bar chart.

I have tried:

- Setting `colorByPoint=true` in `pie` options, which sets different color to each bar.
- Setting `color` to each `JSON` in `series`, which doesn't work as expected.

But as shown in picture, I want different color for each stack.
 [image: here]

Comment: First paste some of your code, you have tried so far. Secondly you can try setting background color in your JS where you are loading the chart by using `document.getEementById('ID').style.backgroundColor=<your_color>` place it in loop change color with respect to your loop index and run on each entry in your chart.

Comment: @WasifAle I have pasted some code I've tried already. Changing color for highcharts isn't that straightforward, so I had to ask here. Could you please help?

Comment: I just suggested if you are trying to change color using JS, so you can run it after DOM load, else you have to set it in chart color property. please check https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors

Comment: Okay, I'll see if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set color for whole series points, or just for one point. There is no other way out, so in order to achieve the effect which is showed on your image, you need to set the different color on every point inside of your series, and then make this color a bit brighter on next series definition.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears']
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    legend: false,
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [{
            y: 2,
          color: '#ff0000' // red
        }, {
            y: 3,
          color: '#00ff00' // green
        }, {
            y: 1,
          color: '#0000ff' // blue
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [{
            y: 1,
          color: '#990000' // medium red
        }, {
            y: 2,
          color: '#009900' // medium green
        }, {
            y: 3,
          color: '#000099' // medium blue
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [{
            y: 3,
          color: '#550000' // dark red
        }, {
            y: 1,
          color: '#005500' // dark green
        }, {
            y: 2,
          color: '#000055' // dark blue
        }]
    }]
});
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/vyamk5cg/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `color` property to set it.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Top',
    data: [
        {y:15, color:'blue'}, 
        {y:64, color:'red'}, 
        {y:27,  color:'green'}, 
        {y:32, color:'yellow'}, 
        {y:17, color:'purple'}
    ]
}.............
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer, but I have already tried this. I also tried `colorByPoint=true` which sets different color to each bar. But as shown in picture, I want different color for each stack. Could you please help for that case?